# Get aws ec2 instance metadata using go sdk v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2

I try this example:
https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/sdk-utilities/ec2-imds/

and go.mod is using:
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/ec2/imds v1.12.15

but the localip prints as:
&{{0xc0002d1680} {map[{}:{[{ false false {map[]}}]}]}}

Anyone have this working?

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem if anyone is interested:
https://github.com/natemarks/ec2metadata

Answer (score 0):

The client.GetMetadata function returns a GetMetadataOutput object with a Content element which is the HTTP resp.Body of type io.Reader. That element needs to be additionally converted to a string, e.g., via a function like this

```
func copyToString(r io.Reader) (res string, err error) {
    var sb strings.Builder
    if _, err = io.Copy(&sb, r); err == nil {
        res = sb.String()
    }
    return
}
```

So, a correct version of the AWS sample should return

```
localip_str, err := copyToString(localip.Content)
```